# Python: manipulate time dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a Pandas dataframe with a numpy.ndarray as content.

```
data_empty = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_empty)
df['HH'] = np.arange(0,10)
```

The dataframe `df['HH']` is a time difference in hours with respect to a fixed date:

```
start_date =['1990-01-01 00:00:00']
```

I would like to get a new Dataframe column `df['new_date']` that shows the actual date in the same format as `df['HH]`. When I try:

```
df['time_added'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['HH'],'h')
df['new_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(start_date)+ df['time_added']
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: cannot add indices of unequal length.
```

I would like to know the answer to two possible solutions:
1) how can I make a dataframe `df['start_date']` all with the value start_date, so I can add start_date to time_added?
2) How can I prevent making a new dataframe all with the same value start_date and just evaluate

```
df['new_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(start_date)+ df['time_added']
```

without having length problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove one element list for `start_date` and for convert timedeltas use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
start_date ='1990-01-01 00:00:00'
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(start_date) + pd.to_timedelta(df['HH'],'h')
print (df)
   HH                Date
0   0 1990-01-01 00:00:00
1   1 1990-01-01 01:00:00
2   2 1990-01-01 02:00:00
3   3 1990-01-01 03:00:00
4   4 1990-01-01 04:00:00
5   5 1990-01-01 05:00:00
6   6 1990-01-01 06:00:00
7   7 1990-01-01 07:00:00
8   8 1990-01-01 08:00:00
9   9 1990-01-01 09:00:00
```

Or use only [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `origin` and `unit` parameters:

```
start_date ='1990-01-01 00:00:00'
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['HH'], unit='h', origin=start_date)
print (df)
   HH                Date
0   0 1990-01-01 00:00:00
1   1 1990-01-01 01:00:00
2   2 1990-01-01 02:00:00
3   3 1990-01-01 03:00:00
4   4 1990-01-01 04:00:00
5   5 1990-01-01 05:00:00
6   6 1990-01-01 06:00:00
7   7 1990-01-01 07:00:00
8   8 1990-01-01 08:00:00
9   9 1990-01-01 09:00:00
```